# Selenium WebDriver, works fine on laptop but not on desktop.WHY?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, c#-4.0, katalon-recorder

I'm using Selenium Webdriver latest version and run the test on Chrome v69.0.3497.100.

When I execute script in my laptop, It working fine and click on the element but on desktop, it find element but can't click.

This is HTML of element:

```
<div class='col-sm-1'>
   <div style="position: relative;margin-top: 19px;left:14px;" class="material-switch">
   <input id="checkHiddenDevice" name="checkHiddenDeviceOption" type="checkbox">
      <input id="checkHiddenDevice" name="checkHiddenDeviceOption"  type="checkbox">
      <label for="checkHiddenDevice" class="label-primary">
      ::before
      ::after
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the Xpath:

```
//div[@class='col-sm-1']
```

I've also tried some xpaths like `//label[@for='checkHiddenDevice']` or find element by CSS but it doesn't work. only xpath `//div[@class='col-sm-1']` is working but in laptop only.

Then I try on KatalonRecorder Tool. When I put my Xpath and run, test case passed because it finds element but didn't click? Then I try to find Xpath by Katalon tool then Katalon generate this Xpath:

```
xpath=(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='#of devices'])[1]/following::label[1]
```

But with this xpath it also can't find element (or I don't know how to change it to right xpath in my code)

Does anyone was faced with such problem?

Comment: What is the issue? Element cant be found?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Timggwp yes cant be found on desktop. and I use the same version of chromedriver and selenium webdriver

Comment: As @Newcontributor said you should provide more details. We can't assume what you have to find what is wrong.

Comment: Sorry. This is question that I want to ask. Why can't I click on element when running on desktop but on laptop is ok. With same code and version of anything (chrome, chrome driver, selenium webdriver.,,,)

Comment: @MinhHuongTraVo Can you try on input using id `checkHiddenDevice` rather then label and let me know

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue. Did your problem for solved? if yes then please suggest me some ways.

The only difference is I'm automating the desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. Even i have faced this issue, this issue might occur when the browser zooming is more than 100%. just execute the same scripts with 90% of browser zoom